# Differentiating $- \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^2} e^{i n \cdot \alpha}\int_0^E\frac{1}{4\pi t}\exp({\omega^2 t - \frac{|x - n - y|^2}{4t^2}})dt$ wrt $x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, summation

I have a formula for the Ewald method which can be used to speed up computations when working with periodic Green's functions. I will need to take the derivative of the function $G(x, y)$ with respect to $x$.

$$G(x, y) = - \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^2} e^{i n \cdot \alpha}\int_0^E\frac{1}{4\pi t}\exp({\omega^2 t - \frac{|x - n - y|^2}{4t^2}})dt$$

where $E$ and $\omega$ are constants. So does anyone know if it is possible to take the derivative of this function?

Comment: Is $n$ real or complex? if it is a real parameter, the absolute value is unnecessary (I assume $x,y$ are both real). If it is complex, the modulus square is anyway real. I don't see any reason to keep the $|\cdot|$ sign anyway. Then you should be able to differentiate under the integral sign. Are you asking what the derivative is, or just if it is 'mathematically justified' to bring the derivative 'through' the summation and the integral?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. And I am asking both if it is mathematically justified to bring the derivative through the summation and the integral, and what the actual derivative is.

Comment: I think the form of the equation arises through the heat kernel - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to derivate G(x,y). The easiest way, in my opinion, is, first, by using the properties of the exponential. e^(x-z) = e^z / e^z, where z=n-y, and the you do the derivate, because the integral only depends on t.